# jquery validation with condition IF

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to achieve the following? for the same field different range validation depending on dropdown value.

Thank You

If blue selected from dropdown then value field should be range from 200-300 if red then range from 0-100

HTML

```
<select name="color" id="Color">
<option value="orange" select="selected">orange</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="value" />
```

SCRIPT

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    value: {
      required: true,
        if ($('#color').val() == "red"){
      range: [0, 100]
    }
      if ($('#color').val() == "blue"){
      range: [200, 300]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

- Any field that you need to validate using this plugin ***must*** contain a `name` attribute.

  ```
  <input type="text" id="value" name="value" />
  ```
- Attach an `.on('change')` handler to the `select` element in conjunction with [the plugin's `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).

  ```
  $('#color').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "blue") {
          $('#value').rules('add', {
              range: [200,300]
          })
      } else if ($(this).val() == "red") {
          $('#value').rules('add', {
              range: [0,100]
          })
      } else {
          $('#value').rules('remove');
      }
  });
  ```
- Declare the `required` rule within `.validate()` to avoid interference by the `.rules()` methods above.

  ```
  $("#myform").validate({
      rules: {
          value: {  // <-- this refers to the "name" attribute
              required: true
          }
      }
  });
  ```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3796X/**

Comment: Thank you, I managed to understand the logic, I have not choose to put the change handler on the select at this time.

Comment: @user2859027, you're welcome.  Since I solved your question as it was presented, please accept my answer.  Thanks.